# How to make non-modal QDialog not cancellable by pressing Esc key?

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

Can I prevent non-modal QDialog from closing when the user hits `Esc`, other than by overriding `reject()` or using event filter / `event` method?
If not, is it possible with a modal QDialog?

Comment: Install event filter? Override key press/release event?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use eventFilter, you can use QShortcut to create a keyboard shortcut for Escape and call the dialog's show slot. This can be done like:

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QShortcut * shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Escape),this,SLOT(show()));
    shortcut->setAutoRepeat(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override eventFilter in your dialog and manage it on your own when Escape is pressed :

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->installEventFilter(this);
}



bool MyDialog::eventFilter(QObject  *obj, QEvent * event)
{

    if((MyDialog *)obj == this && event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress && ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key() == Qt::Key_Escape )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask is can it be done without overriding any of the `QDialog`'s methods / slots, and without using the event filter.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, well, yes, you can patch QDialog and build your version of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Create a QObject-based class to receive the events: -

```
class MyEvents : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyEvents(QObject* parent);

    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
        {
            if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) 
            {
                QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
                if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
                    return true;
                else
                    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
            } 
            else 
            {
               // standard event processing
               return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
            }
        }
};
```

Then install the object as an event filter for the dialog

```
MyEvents* myEvents = new MyEvents;

QDialog myDialog(parent);
myDialog->installEventFilter(myEvents);
```